# PHP error on re-creating image

Tags: php, image, gd

Here is my code

```
$file = 'test.png';
$img = imagecreatefrompng($file);
header('Content-Type:image/png');
imagepng($img, $file, 100);
```

I always get this error and can't able to render

```
The image “image_path” cannot be displayed because it contains errors.
```

What do you think is my error?

Comment: If you just want to output the image, you do not need to load it via `imagecreatefrompng`, which is useful for *editing* images. Just [`readfile`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.readfile.php) the existing image file right to the output.

Comment: That isn't the correct way to set the `Content-Type`.

Comment: I suppose you should call `imagepng($img, NULL, 100);`. If you put path in this function call it'll try to save file on disk, and response sended to browser is empty.

Comment: oh.. sorry.. i paste a wrong code.. updated.. still the same error

Answer (score 0):

I think there might be two errors here. The header name should be:

```
header('Content-Type: image/png');
```

And since you probably wanted to output the image data again (not save it back), you have to omit the filename:

```
imagepng($img, NULL, 100);
```

If you are still getting that browser error, then probe if the file correctly downloads with:

```
wget -S http://www.example.com/test.php
```

Verify header and content size. If your PHP script for example contains the infamous UTF-8 BOM, then not only will the header be wrong, but also garbage decorate the PNG data, thus rendering it invalid.